# Function for Input and Text

Tags: javascript, function, input

I am trying to create a function that puts the text you click on into 3 input boxes in order from box 1 to Box 3. However with the function below, the text appears in Box 1 & 3 at the same time and then Box 2. How can I fix this?

```
function setInput(id){
if(hasbeenset)
{
    document.getElementById("myinput2").value= id;
}
else if
(hasbeenset=true)

{
    document.getElementById("myinput").value=id;

}
   else 
    (hasbeenset=true)
   {
    document.getElementById("myinput3").value=id;

   }


   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is wrong because you haven't specified a condition for your `else if`:

```
}
else if {  // invalid syntax
```

You should have:

```
}
else if ( condition goes here ) {
```

UPDATE:

With your edits, you now have two problems.

```
else if
(hasbeenset=true)
```

This will *set* `hasbeenset` to true, and will always succeed because the expression evaluates to true.

```
else 
(hasbeenset=true)
```

This is invalid syntax, an `else` block never takes an expression.